# Show & Hide Rows Based on Check Boxes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, javascript-objects

I will begin by saying that I am incredibly inexperienced with coding, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I  am trying to show/hide rows based on whether a checkbox is ticked or not. For example, I have a checkbox in A5 - If it is unchecked, I want it to hide rows 6:18, and if it is checked, I want it to show rows 6:18.

The same goes for a checkbox in A19, to hide/show rows 20:26 respectively. A27 for rows 28:37 etc.

I have found a previous forum post, in which I will link the code below, however the first checkbox is hiding ALL rows (Eg. if A5 is unchecked, it is hiding rows 6:18, 20:26 AND 28:37. When it is then checked, it is only showing rows 6:18.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var cfg = { // Please set this object.
    A5: {startRow: 6, endRow: 18},
    A19: {startRow: 20, endRow: 26},
    A27: {startRow: 28, endRow: 37},
  };

  var activeRange = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var ranges = Object.keys(cfg);
  if (cfg[activeRange]) {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var values = sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).getValues();
    values.forEach(function(e, i) {
      if (e[0]) {
        sheet.showRows(cfg[ranges[i]].startRow, cfg[ranges[i]].endRow - cfg[ranges[i]].startRow);
      } else {
        sheet.hideRows(cfg[ranges[i]].startRow, cfg[ranges[i]].endRow - cfg[ranges[i]].startRow);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

As discussed, the first checkbox is hiding ALL rows (Eg. if A5 is unchecked, it is hiding rows 6:18, 20:26 AND 28:37. When it is then checked, it is only showing rows 6:18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to hide the rows from 6 to 18, when the checkbox of "A5" is unchecked.
- You want to hide the rows from 20 to 26, when the checkbox of "A19" is unchecked.
- You want to hide the rows from 28 to 37, when the checkbox of "A27" is unchecked.
- When the checkbox is checked, you want to show the rows.
- You want to achieve above using the OnEdit event trigger with Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### From:

```
var values = sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).getValues();
values.forEach(function(e, i) {
  if (e[0]) {
```

#### To:

```
var values = sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).getValues().filter(String); // Modified
values.forEach(function(e, i) {
  if (e[0] === true) { // Modified
```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.